# Correct usage of std::shared_ptr and std::auto_ptr

Tags: smart-pointers

I know the basic definition of the following smart types and how to use them. However I am not very sure on the places/circumstances 
where :

- `std::auto_ptr` should be preferred over `std::shared_ptr`.
- `std::shared_ptr` should be preferred over `std::auto_ptr`.
- `std::auto_ptr` : used to ensures that the object to which it points gets destroyed automatically when control leaves a block.
- `std::shared_ptr` : wraps a reference-counted smart pointer around a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: You have a correct summary of what the two types do. I don't really see what the question is; you use the one that provides behaviour X when you need behaviour X, and the one that provides behaviour Y when you need behaviour Y. If you "know" these definitions but don't really **understand** them, then you're going to have to be more specific.

Answer (score 5):

`auto_ptr` should never be used because it is deprecated as of C++11<sup>1</sup>.

Use

1. `std::shared_ptr` if ownership is to be *shared*
2. `std::unique_ptr` if there should only be a *unique* view of the object, i.e. only one owner

`auto_ptr` can also not be used in standard containers as it is not copyable.

---

<sup>1: `D.10 auto_ptr`: "The class template auto_ptr is deprecated. [ Note: The class template unique_ptr (20.7.1) provides a better solution. —end note"</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In the case there is only one owner, use lightweight std::unique_ptr. For more complicated scenarios use std::shared_ptr.

There is no reason to use std::auto_ptr: new smart pointers shared_ptr, unique_ptr and weak_ptr contain all required functionality. unique_ptr class supersedes auto_ptr

Answer (score 0):

You use an auto_ptr (or unique_ptr in C++11) when one distinguished pointer instance has full ownership of the pointee. That is, if you can always look at the code and point with your finger at one instance of std::auto_ptr that owns the object the pointer points at, you have a good use case fo auto_ptr.

If things are not so clear, you use a shared_ptr. If in doubt and in a single-threaded environment, use a shared_ptr.